# Set custom product price attribute as default product price

Tags: product, price, custom-attributes

I have made one product attribute `myprice`. and showing as input field in admin.

I want to use that `myprice` attribute as product's price instead of default price, thus products price on frontend would be that of `myprice` attribute value instead of default price.

How can I achieve this ?

Thanks.

Comment: The question is why would you need this ?

Comment: I have multiple websites, and now I need to show different prices for different websites.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Magento already has this feature. You can set different prices for different sites. However you cannot set different prices for multiple stores that comes under a particular websites. If your scope is website, you can achieve it by setting the price scope to `website` in sytem configuration `System > Configuration > Catalog > Catalog > Price`.

For more info, follow these links and make an idea. [**LINK1**](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/4339/is-it-possible-to-have-different-price-and-currency-per-product-and-per-store-vi) , [**LINK2**](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/7283/problems-configuring-magento-the-catalog-price-scope), [**LINK3**](http://www.unchi.co.uk/2012/11/14/multiple-base-prices-in-magento/)